# I need % symbol after Textbox in zendform

Tags: zend-framework, textbox, zend-form

HI,,

I need a % symbol after my textbox in zendform..

Here i am wrote this code its displace lable and textbox.

$fee = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('fee_percentage','fee_percentage');
        $fee->setLabel('Fee:')

If i want % symbol after textbox what should i write?

Please do favour..

thanks 
kiran

Answer (score 1):

You could use my AnyMarkup decorator: http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62

```
$fee->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('AnyMarkup', array(
      'markup' => '<span class="percentsign">%</span>'),
      'placement' => 'append'
    ),
    'HtmlTag',
    'Label'
  )
);
```

Comment: See "Custom decorators" at this URL: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html on how to integrate custom decorators.

Comment: I used this code its working for me..->setDescription('%')
                   ->setDecorators(array(
             'ViewHelper',
                       array('Description', array('placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND, 'tag' => 'em')),
                       array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
                       array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
                       ))